# CSS to select elements which have three different classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I use client side CSS ([Stylus extension](https://add0n.com/stylus.html)) to modify the appearance of a website that I use. The site's CSS class names are programmatically generated, not mnemonic or explanatory, and frequently change: the class names all have the form of alternating letters and digits, so one day an element will have `1a2b3c` as a class while the next day it will be `8x9y0z`.  So instead of using class names I have to write selectors which depend on the structure of the HTML via copious use of `>` and `:nth-child`.  This works for the most part, except for a few things where the structure changes from page to page with nothing in the URL to indicate which structure is going to be used.  One thing that *doesn't* change is that the element I'm interested in always has an ancestor which has three different CSS classes, while all other elements always have exactly two classes. `div[class*=" "]` will select `div` elements with at least two classes, but I can see no way to select elements with at least (or exactly) three classes.

Comment: and you know the classes? or at least one of them?

Comment: *div[class*=" "] will select div elements with at least two classes* --> it can also select `class="one "` so it also target one class

Comment: @TemaniAfif The class names change from day to day and have forms like "1a2b3d" which are programmatically generated.

Comment: you have at least the control over the whitespace? are you sure it will always be `class="a b c"` and not `class="a b c "` ?

Comment: There is no standard CSS selector predicate for "number-of-classes", sorry.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The elements with three classes always have exactly two spaces, and the elements with two classes always have exactly one space/.